# ListPreference with duplicate values

Tags: android

I want to display list of languages in settings preferences.

```
Abkhaz
Afar
...
English
...
Zulu
```

I am using ListPreference to do this. Languages are sorted alphabetically but that's a long list so I want to add 3 most popular languages on top of the list. That means adding duplicate values in the language list.

```
English
...
Abkhaz
Afar
...
English
...
Zulu
```

The problem is that I cannot control which entry is selected when list is displayed. If the language is one of the 3 popular I want the entry on top of the list to be selected not the one in the middle of the alphabetical order.

```
mListPreference.setEntryValues(R.array.LanguageCodes);
mListPreference.setEntries(R.array.Languages);
mListPreference.setValueIndex(1);  //does not work as expected, item selected is in the middle of the list
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have different entry values for the duplicate entries. In code these should mean the same entry.